# Call to unavailable function 'system': not available on iOS

Tags: c++, cocos2d-x

I'm new to cocos2d-x and while compiling my project I get this error.

> Call to unavailable function 'system': not available on iOS

I see this call is no longer applicable but, what can I use to replace it?
Any insight would be appreciated!

```
bool FileUtils::removeDirectory(const std::string& path)
{
#if !defined(CC_TARGET_OS_TVOS)
    std::string command = "rm -r ";
    // Path may include space.
    command += "\"" + path + "\"";
    if (system(command.c_str()) >= 0) /*System Call Error/Not Availible*/
        return true;
    else
        return false;
 #else
    return false;
#endif
}
```

Comment: "It's in FileUtils::removeDirectory(const std::string& path) and the deprecation text for system is -> Use posix_spawn APIs instead." -- found in a link off the link on the PR below

Answer (score 2):

`system` function is not available on iOS 11, there is a accepted [PR](https://github.com/cocos2d/cocos2d-x/pull/17921) for the same issue.

Now we're using `nftw` instead of `system`.
Update your source with `v3` branch of cocos2d-x repo.

Answer (score 2):

system function is not available on iOS 11
Use this mean while until Oct 9 we can have new cocos2d-x 3.16

**if (command.size() >= 0)**

Answer (score 0):

I have not confirmed this, but you might try something like the following:

```
//  This is ugly, but it should work
if (fork() == 0)
{
    string fullpath = "\"" + _storagePath + "\"";
    string arg1 = "-r";
    char* args[] =
    {
        &arg1.at(0),
        &fullpath.at(0),
        nullptr,
    };
    const char* command = "rd";
    execvp(command, args);
}
```