# AssetsManager.cpp - Call to unavailable function 'system': not available on iOS

Tags: c++, ios, xcode, cocos2d-x, ios11

When I run a cocos2dx game in Xcode 9.1, I get the following error:

> game/cocos2d/extensions/assets-manager/AssetsManager.cpp:660:5: Call
>   to unavailable function 'system': not available on iOS

Version used: cocos2d-x-3.2  Jul.17 2014

In code, this line throws the error:

```html
    system(command.c_str());
```

How to resolve this issue, since "system" is removed from iOS 11???

[image: Xcode Error]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Call to unavailable function 'system': not available on iOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45420717/call-to-unavailable-function-system-not-available-on-ios)

Comment: Yeah. No helpful responses so far :-(

Answer (score 0):

This is a known issue, according to [this github issue](https://github.com/cocos2d/cocos2d-x/issues/17907) for Cocos2d. It appears to be resolved, I'd dig around there to solve this.